# VSCode: can't figure out Hit Count condition

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

This should be such an easy question to answer. I'm a bit of a newbie to Visual Studio Code and I'm struggling to work out how to get the "Hit Count" conditional breakpoint feature to work. I've got a simple for loop set up like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  cout << i << endl;
}
```

I put a breakpoint on the cout line, right-clicked it and clicked "Edit Breakpoint..." and changed the drop-down box to "Hit Count". I want to simply have the breakpoint fire on the 5th iteration through the for loop, but I can't figure out how to write the expression. No matter what I write, the program breaks at the first pass through the loop. I've tried "5", "== 5" and "Hit Count == 5" but nothing works.

[image]

If anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong, I'd be grateful! All the stuff I can find online is about Visual Studio and not VSCode.

Comment: Maybe related? https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/714

Comment: I think it might be. I followed what was written in this comment and it worked the same: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/714#issuecomment-663528553

Answer (score 14):

This link helps you.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/13211

I think, If you want to use it when hit-count is 5, you can write '= 5'.

example

- '> 10' break after 10 hits
- '< 3'  break on the first two hits
- '= 10' same 10
- '>= 10' Greater than or equal to 10.

For me,(using javascript)
You can see the change(**the output value 'i'**) in the left **'watch' section**.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2GhG.gif)

- 1-hit-count, **the output value 'i'**: 0
- 2-hit-count, **the output value 'i'**: 1
- 3-hit-count, **the output value 'i'**: 2
- 4-hit-count, **the output value 'i'**: 3
- 5-hit-count, **the output value 'i'**: 4
- 6-hit-count, **the output value 'i'**: 5
- 7-hit-count, **the output value 'i'**: 6
- 8-hit-count, **the output value 'i'**: 7
- 9-hit-count, **the output value 'i'**: 8
- 10-hit-count, **the output value 'i'**: 9

I set **"hit-count '>= 5' "**.
so 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9(**the output value 'i'**) are printed

I hope this helps

Answer (score 7):

The Hit Count feature is **NOT** supported by the GDB C++ debugger.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).